# How to solve JavaFX problem for using pop-up notifications

Tags: java, javafx

I am learning JavaFX and my IDE for doing that is NetBeans IDE 8.2. 
I have a problem when I want to run a project.
my sample project is Drag and Drop a picture on ImageView by scene builder.
the error is:

```
Executing C:\Users\Mohammad Sadeghi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DragDrop\dist\run1057050476\DragDrop.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$159(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.image.ImageView cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Parent
at dragdrop.DragDrop.start(DragDrop.java:22)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$166(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
... 1 more
Exception running application dragdrop.DragDrop
Java Result: 1
```

my FXMLDocument.fxml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>


<ImageView fx:id="ImgID" fitHeight="228.0" fitWidth="248.0" onDragDone="#ondragdone" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="dragdrop.FXMLDocumentController"/>
```

FXMLDocumentController.java :

```
    /*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package drag-drop;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;

/**
 *
 * @author Mohammad Sadeghi
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private ImageView ImgID;

    public FXMLDocumentController() {
    }

    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

    @FXML
    private void ondragdone(DragEvent event) {

        List<File> fi=event.getDragboard().getFiles();

         try {
            Image img=new Image(new FileInputStream(fi.get(0)));

            ImgID.setImage(img);
        } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("ERROR");
        }

    }
}
```

and my Main app() is :

```
public class DragDrop extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
     Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
  }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
  }

}
```

I don't know what is this error for !!
I have almost the same error on another JavaFX project when I am using of Scenebuilder.
could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the signature of [`FXMLLoader#load(URL)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load(java.net.URL)) you'll see:

```java
public static <T> T load​(URL location) throws IOException
```

Notice the `<T>`? That makes the method generic and the type parameter is used as the return type of the method. This is what allows you to assign the result of calling `#load(URL)` to a variable of any type, such as you're doing.

```java
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

You could literally change the type of `root` to any other type and the code would still compile. Currently, however, the above code has `T` being inferred as `Parent`. Under the hood this uses a cast, same as you would have to do if the `#load(URL)` method returned `Object` instead of `T`.

```java
Parent root = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

The problem is your FXML declares the root element to be an `ImageView`. This means the actual type of object being returned by the `#load(URL)` method is `ImageView`, not `Parent`, and the `ImageView` class is not a subtype of `Parent`—thus the `ClassCastException`.

One option is to use `ImageView root = ...;`. However, this is not sufficient because you are attempting to use `root` as the root of a `Scene` which must be a `Parent`. The better solution is to wrap `ImageView` in a `Parent` in the FXML file. Here's an example using a `StackPane`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
           fx:controller="dragdrop.FXMLDocumentController">
  <ImageView fx:id="ImgID" fitHeight="228.0" fitWidth="248.0" onDragDone="#ondragdone" 
             pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true"/>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: Thanks.it works. but now it does not allow to drop an image on Imageview. I would appreciate if you could help me again.

Comment: That's a separate question. But from your code you don't appear to be properly implementing drag-and-drop. For instance, you don't specify an `onDragOver` handler which is where you would indicate if a drop can be accepted or not.

Comment: Nor do you implement `onDragDropped` which is where you'd actually handle the drop.